# Python Multiprocessing using Process: Consuming Large Memory

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-multiprocessing

I am running multiple processes from single python code:

Code Snippet:

```
while 1:
   if sqsObject.msgCount() > 0:
        ReadyMsg = sqsObject.readM2Q()
        if ReadyMsg == 0:
            continue
        fileName = ReadyMsg['fileName']
        dirName  = ReadyMsg['dirName']
        uuid         = ReadyMsg['uid']
        guid         = ReadyMsg['guid']
        callback     = ReadyMsg['callbackurl']

        # print ("Trigger Algorithm Process")
        if(countProcess < maxProcess):

           try:
             retValue = Process(target=dosomething, args=(dirName, uuid,guid,callback))
             processArray.append(retValue)
             retValue.start()
             countProcess = countProcess + 1
           except:
             print "Cannot Run Process"
        else:
           for i in range(len(processArray)):
              if (processArray[i].is_alive() == True):
                 continue
              else:
                 try:
                    #print 'Restart Process'
                    processArray[i] = Process(target=dosomething, args=(dirName,uuid,guid,callback))
                    processArray[i].start()
                 except:
                    print "Cannot Run Process"


   else: # No more request to service

       for i in range(len(processArray)):
            if (processArray[i].is_alive() == True):
                processRunning = 1
                break
            else:
                continue

      if processRunning == 0:
           countProcess = 0

      else:
           processRunning = 0
```

Here I am reading the messages from the queue and creating a process to run the algorithm on that message. I am putting upper limit of maxProcess. And hence after reaching maxProcess, I want to reuse the processArray slots  which are not alive by checking is_alive().

This process runs fine for smaller number of processes however, for large number of messages say 100, Memory consumption goes through roof. I am thinking I have leak by reusing the process slots.

Not sure what is wrong in the process.

Thank you in advance for spotting an error or wise advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is, in a word, weird :-)

It's not [an mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so no one else can test it, but just looking at it, you have this (slightly simplified) structure in the inner loop:

```
if count < limit:
    ... start a new process, and increment count ...
else:
    do things that can potentially start even more processes
    (but never, ever, decrease count)
```

which seems unwise at best.

There are no invocations of a process instance's `join()`, anywhere.  (We'll get back to the outer loop and its `else` case in a bit.)

Let's look more closely at the inner loop's `else` case code:

```
   for i in range(len(processArray)):
        if (processArray[i].is_alive() == True):
```

Leaving aside the unnecessary `== True` test—which is a bit of a risk, since the `is_alive()` method does not specifically promise to return `True` and `False`, just something that works boolean-ly—consider [this description from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) (this link goes to py2k docs but py3k is the same, and your `print` statements imply your code is py2k anyway):

> `is_alive()`
>
> Return whether the process is alive.
>
> Roughly, a process object is alive from the moment the `start()` method returns until the child process terminates.

Since we can't see the code for `dosomething`, it's hard to say whether these things ever terminate.  Probably they do (by exiting), but if they don't, or don't soon enough, we could get problems here, where we just drop the message we pulled off the queue in the outer loop.

If they *do* terminate, we just drop the process reference from the array, by overwriting it:

```
            processArray[i] = Process(...)
```

The previous value in processArray[i] is discarded.  It's not clear if you may have saved this anywhere else, but if you have not, the Process instance gets discarded, and now it is actually *impossible* to call its `join()` method.

Some Python data structures tend to clean themselves up when abandoned (e.g., open streams flush output and close as needed), but the multiprocess code appears not to auto-join() its children.  So this could be the, or a, source of the problem.

Finally, whenever we do get to the `else` case in the outer loop, we have the same somewhat odd search for any alive processes—which, incidentally, can be written more clearly as:

```
if any(p.is_alive() for p in processArray):
```

as long as we don't care about which *particular* ones are alive, and which are not—and if none report themselves as alive, we reset the count, but never do anything with the variable `processArray`, so that each `processArray[i]` still holds the identity of the Process instance.  (So at least we could call `join` on each of these, excluding any lost by overwriting.)

Rather than building your own `Pool` yourself, you are probably better off using `multiprocess.Pool` and its `apply` and `apply_async` methods, as in [miraculixx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38821501/1256452).

Comment: Impressed... thanks for the response. That was very helpful. I learnt a lot from your response. Every word in your response makes sense. Thanks for responding..

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure what is wrong in the process.

It appears you are creating as many processes as there are messages, even when the maxProcess count is reached.

> I am thinking I have leak by reusing the process slots.

There is no need to manage the processes yourself. Just use a [process pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers):

```
 # before your while loop starts
 from multiprocessing import Pool
 pool = Pool(processes=max_process)
 while 1:
   ...
   # instead of creating a new Process
   res = pool.apply_async(dosomething, 
                          args=(dirName,uuid,guid,callback)) 
 # after the while loop has finished
 # -- wait to finish
 pool.close()
 pool.join()
```

**Ways to submit jobs**

Note that the [`Pool` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) supports several ways to submit jobs:

- apply_async - one message at a time
- map_async - a chunk of messages at a time

If messages arrive fast enough it might be better to collect several of them (say 10 or 100 at a time, depending on the actual processing done) and use `map` to submit a "mini-batch" to the target function at a time:

```
...
while True:
    messages = []
    # build mini-batch of messages
    while len(messages) < batch_size:
        ... # get message
        messages.append((dirName,uuid,guid,callback))
    pool.map_async(dosomething, messages)
```

To avoid memory leaks left by `dosomething` you can ask the Pool to restart a process after it has consumed some number of messages:

```
max_tasks = 5 # some sensible number
Pool(max_processes, maxtasksperchild=max_tasks)
```

**Going distributed**

If with this approach the memory capacity is still exceeded, consider using a distributed approach i.e. add more machines. Using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) that would be pretty straight forward, coming from the above:

```
# tasks.py
@task
def dosomething(...):
   ... # same code as before

# driver.py
  while True:
     ... # get messages as before
     res = somefunc.apply_async(args=(dirName,uuid,guid,callback))
```

Comment: thanks @miraculixx for the response.First time I am working with multiprocessing python, and struggling to understand pool.apply_async. So if I am understanding it correctly, then in "while 1:" loop, code will read the message from the queue and will apply_async to the pool. However, at any given time, pool will only run maxprocess as defined by: pool = Pool(processes=max_process).  Now when ever all messages in queue has been processed then run pool.close() and pool.join().Please let me know if my understanding is wrong!! I havent used Celery before but if this doesnt work shall try that.

Comment: thanks for confirming. It sounds like pool does exactly what I was trying to do explicitly using Process and arrays. Will give it try. Thanks once again.